# Datatable and J query table search - create corresponding graphs to data in searches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm creating a webpage that will allow us to search for access to care grants. I have the datatables and jquery part down, but I'd like to have some visuals to accompany my results.  In my code, I have 2 grants; 1 VA, 1 Duke University.  I'd like a pie chart in a separate container that would show VA 50% and Duke 50%. Similarly, if I searched for "SDR" one VA grant would come up and I would want it to show 100% VA grants.  Is such a thing possible with something like Bootstrap or Google Charts? If so, and you'd be willing to help me with my code, I'd be very grateful.

`````
````<head>

````<title>My access grant search title</title>

````<link ````href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTable````s.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
````<link rel="stylesheet" ````href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
````<script ````src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
````</script>
````<script ````src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
````</script>
````<script ````src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.````min.js"></script>

````<script>$(document).ready(function() {
````  $('#example').DataTable({
````    responsive: {
````      details: {
````        type: 'column',
````        target: 5
````      }
````    },
````    columnDefs: [{
````      className: 'btn-info',
````      orderable: false,
````      targets: 5
````    }],
````  });
````});</script>

````<table id="example" class="display">
````  <thead>
````    <tr>
````      <th class="all">Project Name</th>
````      <th class="all">Project Number</th>
````      <th class="all">PI(s)</th>
````      <th class="all">End Date</th>
````      <th class="all">Organization</th>
````      <th class="all">Abstract</th>
````      <th class="none"></th>
````    </tr>
````  </thead>
````  <tbody>
````      <tr>

````      <td>Geographic Access to VHA Rehabilitation Services for OEF/OIF ````Veterans</td>
````      <td>DHI 06-010</td>
````      <td>Cowper Ripley, Diane</td>
````      <td>2007-09-30</td>
````      <td>VA</td>
````    <td>
````    <button type=""button"" class=""btn btn-info"" data- ````toggle=""collapse"" data-target=""#example"">Expand</button>
````    </td>

````     <td>(1) To identify a cohort of Operation Enduring Freedom ````(OEF)/Operation Iraqi Freedom (OIF) combat veterans who accessed Veterans ````Health Administration (VHA) facilities for conditions and injuries ````sustained while on active duty.</td></tr>
````<tr>

````      <td>A Role of Multilevel Healthcare Access Dimensions in Ovarian ````Cancer Disparities</td>
````      <td>R37CA233777</td>
````      <td>AKINYEMIJU, TOMI F;</td>
````      <td>2020-04-30</td>
````      <td>DUKE UNIVERSITY</td>
````    <td>
````    <button type=""button"" class=""btn btn-info"" data- ````toggle=""collapse"" data-target=""#example"">Expand</button>
````    </td>

````      <td>*No changes from original application* Narrative Ovarian cancer ````(OC) survival has improved over the past several decades as new, frontline ````treatment strategies have been developed.</td></tr>

````  </tbody>
````</table>
`````

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.